# In GMail, is it possible to reverse "always display images from" decisions?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I force images to hide in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21894/how-do-i-force-images-to-hide-in-gmail)

GMail hides images by default, and provides an "always display images from [sender's e-mail address]" link at the top of messages with hidden images. Is it possible to change a sender back to "don't show images" status after "always display" has been selected? If so, how?

Comment: See [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21894/how-do-i-force-images-to-hide-in-gmail) for an up-to-date solution.