# How do I force images to hide in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, e-mails from "strangers" automatically have their images blocked. I accidentally selected to always display images from the sender. However, I would like to undo this decision and begin hiding the images again.

Is there any way that I can tell Gmail to block images from a particular sender?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Load up the email and in the email header click the little drop down arrow:

[image: Gmail - Header]

Then click the `Don't display from now on` link

[image: Gmail - Don't display images]

Comment: Ok, so what if that option doesn't show up when you push the little down arrow? Then how do you get it to stop showing images?

Comment: @Will I would make sure you have JavaScript enabled as a starter otherwise I am not sure as it still works for me.

Comment: For anyone else who as user22830's problem: it's to do with the Gmail's new "Always display images" option; uncheck that option, save settings, then **refresh** the tab itself to get back this choice in the "Show details" menu.

Answer (score 10):

If you click the Show Details link at the top of your e-mail message (or the small arrow next to "to me" in the newest version), you will see this message if you currently display images for that sender. "Images from this sender are always displayed. **Don't display from now on**."

"Don't display from now on" will be a link that you can click to disable showing images for that sender.

Comment: What if it is the reverse case ie I accidentally turned "always display images" to off (ie Gmail set to NOT display images from sender by mistake) and I want to turn it back on? When I go to the Show Details link, the reverse option is not there, unlike in the original case above.

Comment: @Ngee Ping Tio: If you turned them off by accident, when you click on Show Details, you will see this just above the e-mail body. "Images are not displayed. Display images below - Always display images from someEmailAddress@someDomain.com"

Answer (score 1):

1. Open an email with images from the respective person
2. Click on **Show details**
3. Click on **Don't display from now on**

From the [Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/now-displaying-images-in-messages-from.html).