# Gmail expands images to full resolution automatically

Tags: gmail, images

A friend of mine just sent me several pictures embedded in his email. We both use Gmail. When I open his email to reply to him, the images are automatically expanded to high-resolution (5,000 pixels horizontally) which makes it very difficult for me to browse through his email, the Gmail interface and even start my response email.

I looked at this thread:
[How do I force images to hide in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21894/how-do-i-force-images-to-hide-in-gmail) but the information there seems to be outdated as I can't find the option `"Don't display from now on"` on my Gmail interface anymore.

Is there a way to ask Gmail to show thumbnails of the pictures embedded/attached in the email, instead of the full resolution images?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, NO, there isn't a way to do this.

It's always good practice to attach the file instead of embedding it. That way the recipient can choose what to do (view or save) whatever their e-mail client.